# get all property names of a subclass in typescript?

Tags: typescript

how could I get all property names of a subclass in typescript? I'm able to get all property names in the class, but it also gives me the ones in the base class, which I don't need.

base class

```
class BaseTestClass {
    public testVar: null = null;
}
```

sub class

```
class TestClass extends BaseTestClass {
    public longNameVar1: null = null;
    public longNameVar2: null = null;
    public longNameVar3: null = null;
    public longNameVar4: null = null;
    public longNameVar5: null = null;

}


let testClass = new TestClass()

let testClassProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(testClass)
console.log(testClassProperties);
```

Comment: If you transcode this **typescript** to javascript, you'll see why `getOwnPropertyNames` must include `testVar` - any property added using `this.propertyname = value` is an "own" property

Answer (score 1):

its because this how its done. if your print your `testClass` object, you could see is testVar is assigned in own property along with others. Nothing is inside **__proto__**

properties which goes in **__proto__** are not considered as object own property